# Excision in "3264 and all that" by Eisenbud-Harris

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

In Proposition 1.14, page 25 in the book "3264 and all that Intersection Theory in Algebraic Geometry" the authors define a right exact sequence:
$$ Z(\mathbb{P}^1 \times X) \rightarrow Z(X) \rightarrow A(X) \rightarrow 0 $$
where the left-hand map takes any subvariety $\Phi \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times X $ to $0$ if $\Phi$ is contained in a fiber of the projection $\mathbb{P}^1 \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ and otherwise to
$$ \langle \Phi \cap ( \lbrace t_0 \rbrace \times X ) \rangle - \langle \Phi \cap ( \lbrace t_1 \rbrace \times X) \rangle. $$

I see the idea of the exact sequence but I can not figure out what $t_0$ and $t_1$ are for a given $\Phi$. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can choose them to be any two distinct rational points: the automorphism group of the projective line is doubly transitive (even triply transitive).

Comment: Could you elaborate on this in an answer, please? I don't get why this transitivity implies that you can choose any two distinct rational points.

Comment: The group $\textbf{PGL}_2$ of automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a dense open subset of $\mathbb{P}^3$.  Thus, the images under the homomorphism are rationally equivalent, independent of the choice of rational point $(t_0,t_1)$ of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \Delta(\mathbb{P}^1)$.

Comment: But in $Z(X)$ we do not take the quotient yet. $Z(X)$ is the free abelian group of the set of subvarieties, so the map is not well defined, right? We need the image to be exactly the same, not rationally equivalent.

Comment: The image is exactly the same. The homomorphisms differ by rational equivalence, but the images are equal.

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$, $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ with coordinates $[\lambda : \mu], [x:y]$ respectively, take $\Phi = \lbrace x \mu - y \lambda =0 \rbrace$. Then take $t_0=[1:0], t_1= [0:1], s_0=[1:1], s_1=[-1:1]$. Then, 
$$ \langle \Phi \cap (\lbrace t_0 \rbrace \times X) \rangle - \langle \Phi \cap (\lbrace t_1 \rbrace \times X) \rangle = \langle [0:1] \rangle - \langle [1:0] \rangle $$
$$ \langle \Phi \cap (\lbrace s_0 \rbrace \times X) \rangle - \langle \Phi \cap (\lbrace s_1 \rbrace \times X) \rangle = \langle [1:1] \rangle - \langle [-1:1] \rangle $$
are these equal?

Comment: @JasonStarr I am not getting what you mean by "homomorphisms differ by rational equivalence". Thanks for your patience.